# i got error with gas limit 1000000 (gas required exceeded limit)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am new in smart-contract, following 1 tutorial, he used 1000000 as gas limit which was fine before but today I faced this error (out of gas), after some searched I found and I replaced 1000000 with 3000000,

my question is, why code worked with 3000000 but show the error with 1000000 ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gas is the term for the amount of ether (ETH) – the native cryptocurrency of Ethereum – required by the network for a user to interact with the network.
So its simple this time around the interaction you did with blockchain must have been more complicated. So it required more operation as a result more gas fee.
Check out this link to learn more about gas [Gas in ethereum](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course it's the most important thing when you type or code smart contracts, so every function you type in smart contract costs gas, and you can calculate it throw https://wiki.learnblockchain.cn/OPCODE_Gas.pdf , after knowing how much gas costs you will do this Calculation

> gas used * gas price * 0.000000001

and you'll know gas price from https://etherscan.io/ .

Comment: gas used * gas price * 0.000000001 calculation will give you the gas price in ether